# Pairwise scatterplot matrix

Tags: python, pandas, vega-lite, altair

How do you make a matrix of pairwise scatterplots in Altair? I know how to do it in matplotlib, but I don't see anything like it in the Altair [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html#scatter-plots) or examples.

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
```

[image]
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot

Comment: Is this example what you're looking for? https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_matrix.html

Comment: @jakevdp Yes, I completely missed it -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the `repeat` operator; see https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_matrix.html

If you'd like a more pandas-like approach to this, the pdvega package can create a vega-lite scatter matrix in one line: https://jakevdp.github.io/pdvega/plotting.html#scatter-matrix

Comment: I believe the updated link to the `pdvega` package is: https://altair-viz.github.io/pdvega/plotting.html#scatter-matrix