# Scatterplot Matrices in Matplotlib: "singular matrix" Error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following .csv data:

```
Simulation Run,[urea] (μM),[NO3-] (μM),[NH4+] (μM),[NO2-] (μM),[O2] (μM),[HCO3-] (μM),[OH-] (μM),[H+] (μM),[H2O] (μM)
/Run_01,1124.3139186264032,49.79709670397852,128.31458304321205,0.0,4.0,140000.0,0.1,0.1,55000000.0
/Run_02,1.0017668367460492e-159,2426.7395169966485,3.1544859186304598e-09,1.975005700484566e-10,4.0,140000.0,0.1,0.1,55000000.0
/Run_03,9.905001536507822e-160,2426.739516996945,2.861369463189477e-09,1.7910618538551373e-10,4.0,140000.0,0.1,0.1,55000000.0
/Run_04,1123.3362048916795,49.7956932352008,130.27141398143655,0.0,4.0,140000.0,0.1,0.1,55000000.0
/Run_05,1101.9594005273052,49.792379912298884,173.02833603309404,0.0,4.0,140000.0,0.1,0.1,55000000.0
```

I would like to plot it in a series of scatterplot matrices to look at the relationships between the different variables. Much like how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919267/pairwise-scatterplot-matrix). **NOTE:** In the linked example the person is asking how to accomplish this in altair. I want to do this in Matplotlib.

[image: scatterplot matrices]

Using the above code as reference, here is the code I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

from math import ceil

    def graph_data(f: str):
        """
        Represents the data
        as a series of scatter-plot matrices.
        """
    
        df = pd.read_csv(f)

        NROWS = ceil((len(df.columns) - 1) / 3)
        # Although the number of variables could vary,
        # I would like no more than 3 charts per row.
        NCOLS = 3
    
        fname = f[:-4] + '.pdf'
    
        with PdfPages(fname) as pdf:
            scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(NROWS, NCOLS), diagonal='kde')
            pdf.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
            plt.close()
```

When I try to run this, here is the error I get:

```
[LOTS OF TRACEBACK]...numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Is this happening because the number of variables isn't a perfect square number (thereby not yielding a square matrix)? Is there a way to avoid this?

***EDIT:***

I forgot to specify my import statements so I have those in now.

Comment: Hi Mr. T, Thank you for the clarifying questions, I'll post the entire traceback.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Several problems arise. By definition, a scatter matrix provides an n x n matrix and plots a scatter plot for column i vs column j data in [row i, column j] of the matrix. Obviously, the diagonal [row i, column i] has to be filled differently - hence, the kde plot for column i of your df. Then, figsize is not (rows, columns) but (width, height) in inches, so your declaration will not work as expected.

Comment: As for the error message - the kernel density cannot be determined, since the values in some columns show no distribution whatsoever - there is just one value for all entries. You can display this with a histogram, though.

Comment: Hi Mr. T, is there a way I could process my data so that it is able to be displayed as a scatterplot matrix? What I have is a bunch of chemical concentrations that I'd like to show the relationships between.

Comment: How many is "a bunch"? Then, I suggest kicking out all data with no variation - what does a scatter plot between two variables tell you, if one of them is constant? This also solves your kde problem. Otherwise, as mentioned, you have to use histplots in the diagonal. Do you have a link to your (abbreviated) data or is it basically what you posted here?